# Is my answer to this limit correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Define a function $ z(x, y) = \frac{11x^3+5y^3}{x^2+y^2} $. Using the continuous extension, what is the value of the following limit:
$$ \lim_{(\Delta x, \Delta y) \rightarrow (0, 0)\\ \text{along the line } x=y \neq 0}{\left(\frac{\Delta z - dz}{\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}}\right)} $$
I computed $\Delta z$ and  the partial derivatives for $ dz $ and set $x = y$. I got $\Delta z = 8\Delta x$ and $ dz = 8\Delta x$; which gives $ 0 $ as the limit after subtraction.
To evaluate $z_{x}$, and $z_{y}$ at the point $ (0, 0) $, I used the following limits: $ \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \left( z_{x}(x, y) \right) $ and $ \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \left( z_{y}(x, y) \right) $ along the line $x=y$. Which give the values $\frac{17}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ respectively. If I use the definition of partial derivatives however, I get, 11 and 5 respectively. Along the line $x=y$, the first one gives $dz = 8dx$, and thus the limit is $0$; and the second one gives $dz = 16dx$, and thus the limit is $32$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I computed $\Delta z$ and  the partial derivatives for $ dz $ and set $x = y$. I got $\Delta z = 8\Delta x$ and $ dz = 8\Delta x$; which gives $ 0 $ as the limit after subtraction.

Comment: The  notation is not clear for me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The notation-convention is defined as follows: $\Delta z(a, b) = z(a + \Delta x, b+\Delta y) - z(a, b)$, and $ dz = z_{x}(a, b)dx+z_{y}(a, b)dy$.

Comment: Without going through the calculation myself, I can still say that $0$ is the right limit, because $dz$ should approximate $\Delta z$ at least that well, as this is a well-behaved function away from $(x,y) = (0,0)$ (and it is $\Delta x, \Delta y$ that are being sent to $0$, not $x, y$ themselves).

Comment: To evaluate $z_{x}$, and $z_{y}$ at the point $ (0, 0) $, I used the following limits: $ \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \left( z_{x}(x, y) \right) $ and $ \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \left( z_{y}(x, y) \right) $ along the line $x=y$. Which give the values $\frac{17}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ respectively. If I use the definition of partial derivatives however, I get, 11 and 5 respectively. Along the line $x=y$, the first one gives $dz = 8dx$, and thus the limit is $0$; and the second one gives $dz = 16dx$, and thus the limit is 32.